# git pull --rebase on a remote branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

I have got a question related to the `git pull --rebase` command: Why isn't it a good idea to use `git pull --rebase` on remote branches? I know that the rebase command rewrites history. But why (and how and in which situations) could this command be evil?

Comment: Try it yourself in [Duo-screenplay](https://github.com/choroba/duo-screenplay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know where got this idea from that using `git pull --rebase` on *remote branches* is particularly evil.

It doesn’t make much sense to begin with: `git pull` *by design* deals with remote repositories, and as such remote branches. There is no way to use it with non-remote branches.

`git pull --rebase` is particularly useful when working locally for a longer time and wanting to merge in changes repeatedly from the remote repository without creating too many merge commits. Whether to use `git pull --rebase` or just `git pull` on local *unpublished* branches is merely personal preference.

As always: Don’t ever rebase published commits and you’re fine. Regardless of how you perform the rebase (whether using `git pull --rebase` or explicit `git rebase`)

Comment: Maybe I was unclear: We are working with feature, or story based remote branches. And at this point in don't get the point with "Don’t ever rebase published commits". How can i rebase published commits? I do some work, commit some code and do a ´git pull --rebase` My own commits are not published an this point. Therefore I cannot rebase published (pushed) commits.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what your workflow is. If you rebase published commits, you are creating new incompatible commit objects, so you are breaking everyone who has the original commits. Published means that you pushed them at some point before. If you didn’t push them, i.e. nobody else has them, then there is no problem with rebasing them.

Comment: Ok, now I think I got it. The rebase affects the "delta"-commits. If these commits (let's say: E, F, G...) are pushed before and are now rebased to E', F', G' then there could occur a problem. But if I rebase my local repo and the commits, that are not in the remote branch, it should be ok?!

Comment: Yeah, rebasing unpublished commits is totally fine, and there really shouldn’t be a problem with it since nobody knows about them anyway.